# How can I use Entity Framework to use an existing database, and how can I use migrations to switch between DB versions?

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

Problem:

You have an existing database that you want to use with EntityFrameworks so that you can make database changes via classes. You also want to be able to use the migration features to switch between versions of the database.

Unfortunately this doesn't work out of the box with an existing database, but you can use the Reverse POCO generator to reverse-engineer your db as if you wrote it from scratch.

Hopefully my step-by-step solution will benefit others, I'm sure I'll be referring to it again in 6 months.

Answer (score 3):

1. Create new project called MyEF (class library project)
2. Install the **EntityFramework Reverse POCO generator** either from [here](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/ee4fcff9-0c4c-4179-afd9-7a2fb90f5838), or within Visual Studio menu Tools|Extensions and Updates menu. select Online|Visual Studio Gallery|Templates|Visual C#|Database, install the `EntityFramework Reverse POCO generator`.
3. Using Package Manager console, install EntityFramework by `Install-Package EntityFramework`
4. Add a new C# item called MyDB.tt using the template: `EntityFramework Rever POCO Code First Generator`
5. Add a connectionStrings section to the app.Config class and point to your database.

e.g.

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=CP8;Initial Catalog=TestDB;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=15;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

6. In the file MyDB.tt, change "MyDbContext" to "DefaultConnection" or whatever your connection name is.  Save the TT file and the Reverse POCO generator will reverse engineer the database and build your code-first classs for you.
7. If your database has a _MigrationHistory table, delete it!
8. In the package manager console (PMC) issue the following

   Enable-Migrations –EnableAutomaticMigrations -Force
   add-migration Initial

   9. Go to your migrations folder and replace the contents of your XXX_Initial.cs class with

   namespace MyEf.Migrations
   {
       using System;
       using System.Data.Entity.Migrations;

   ```
   public partial class Initial : DbMigration
   {
       public override void Up()
       {           
       }

       public override void Down()
       {
       }
   }
   ```

   }

   10. From the PMC, issue: `update-database`
   11. Change your Model by editing the adding a new property in MyDb.cs to the MyTable class:

   // MyTable
   public class MyTable
   {
       public int Id { get; set; } // Id (Primary key)
       public string Name { get; set; } // Name
       public string Sex { get; set; } // Sex
       public int? Age { get; set; } // Age
       public bool AmIAwesomeOrWhat { get; set; }
   }

   12. Rebuild the solution
   13. Issue a command to save your new migration, and update the database

   add-migration MyNewProperty
   update-database

The following commands will switch to whatever Migration you want.

```
update-database -targetmigration:Initial
update-database -targetmigration:MyNewProperty
```

Comment: EntityFramework Reverse POCO generator is not a NuGet package.

Comment: Migrations are built into the latest version of the generator (available at www.reversepoco.com). In the .tt file, give MigrationConfigurationFileName a name and your set.